# "sudo apt update" fails to download packages

Tags: debian, package-management, upgrade

When trying to do `sudo apt update` on my server I get the following error:

```
<... Removed for clarity ...>

Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                         
Get:37 http://deb.freexian.com wheezy-lts-kernel/main amd64 Packages [11.8 kB]                                                                    
Err http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com stretch InRelease                                                                                          
  
Get:38 http://nsolid-deb.nodesource.com jessie/main amd64 Packages [1467 B]                                       
Get:39 http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/4.0/main amd64 Packages [16.0 kB]                                                      
Ign http://deb.freexian.com wheezy-lts/contrib Translation-en                                                                            
Ign http://deb.freexian.com wheezy-lts/main Translation-en                                                        
Ign http://deb.freexian.com wheezy-lts/non-free Translation-en                              
Ign http://deb.freexian.com wheezy-lts-kernel/main Translation-en                           
Err http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com stretch-updates InRelease                            
  
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/4.0/main Translation-en                      
Ign http://nsolid-deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en       
Err http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com stretch Release.gpg            
  Temporary failure resolving 'debian.uberglobalmirror.com'
Err http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com stretch-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'debian.uberglobalmirror.com'
Fetched 20.4 kB in 2s (8219 B/s)                
Reading package lists... Done
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
112695A0E562B32A
W: Failed to fetch http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.froxlor.org/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.froxlor.org/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/dists/stretch/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'debian.uberglobalmirror.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/dists/stretch-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'debian.uberglobalmirror.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Version of debian:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:        8.11
Codename:       jessie
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- Entering `unset http_proxy` and `unset https_proxy` in the console
- Changed the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the following:

```
deb http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://debian.uberglobalmirror.com/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
```

- The following commands from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used):

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/ 
sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M" -O /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list
sudo apt-get update
```

- `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89729/a-problem-occurred-when-checking-for-updates-error).
- `apt-get clean`

I have read lots of articles but none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your errors are due `jessie` being EOL since 09.07.2020. I'd recommend fresh install a.s.a.p. with stable `buster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of issues here.

- Jessie hasn't been supported since June 2020, so you need to remove all references to it because it's not going to be in the package repositories any more
- Stretch is available but only in LTS until June 2022
- Buster is the current "stable"
- You're getting `Temporary failure resolving 'debian.uberglobalmirror.com'`. It's [no longer](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) a repository server so I'd suggest you replace that, and indeed your entire `sources.list` set, with the [recommended entries](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Repository_URL), replacing `buster` with `stretch` if you must,

  ```
    deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

    deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

    deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
  ```
- You may need to install a more up-to-date package signing key
- You might be best starting over with a fresh installation of "buster"; it's no fun trying to upgrade from a release version that's no longer in the repositories (been there...)